# Angular5 Instascan - addListener Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5

### Angular5 Instascan - addListener Not Working

innerHTML >> It's not working. but alert and outside the function>> It's work

```
scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
  //console.log(content); //It's work
  //alert(content); //It's work 
  this.text2.innerHTML=content; //It's not working.
  this.setText(content); //send to other functions >>It's not working.
});
```

Comment: Replace `function (content) {` with `(content) => {`

Comment: @yurzui It's work. I feel very good. Thank u so match.

Comment: Glad to hear you understand why it should work. If you don't then read https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: @yurzui Thank u so match.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scanner.addListener('scan', function (content) {
  //console.log(content); //It's work
  //alert(content); //It's work 
  this.text2 = content; // <--- Change to this
  this.setText(content); //send to other functions >>It's not working.
});
```

And on your element:

```
<some-element>{{text2}}</some-element>
```